# Getting an empty list when appending values with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using Python 3.5 to edit a list, which in this case is `predictions_dict['D']`, included in the dictionary `predictions_dict`. This is the code that I use:

```
import multiprocessing as multip

predictions_dict = {'A': [],
                    'B': [],
                    'C': [],
                    'D': [],
                    'E': [],
                    'F': [],
                    'Def': []}

data = [{'index': 1, 'rank': 'A'}, {'index': 2, 'rank': 'D'}, {'index': 3, 'rank': 'E'}]
prediction = [(1, 'C'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'D')]


def create_predictions_dict(index, rank):
    for j in data:
        if j['index'] == index:
            predictions_dict[rank].append((index, j['rank'], rank))
            break

np = multip.cpu_count()
p = multip.Pool(processes=np)
_ = p.starmap(create_predictions_dict, prediction)
p.close()
p.join()

print('final list:', predictions_dict['D'])
```

when I execute this code, the output I get is:

```
final list: []
```

And I don't understand why, as I would expect to get:

```
final list: [(2, 'D', 'D'), (3, 'E', 'D')]
```

Comment: Your separate processes are not sharing state.

Comment: How do I correct that?

Comment: It is [non-trivial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: why was `(1, 'A', 'C')` missed from the result?

Comment: Because in `predictions_dict['D']` (the value that gets printed) only tuples that end with `'D'` should appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a solution, thanks to the fact that in the comments the problem was identified as the fact that processes don't share state:

```
import multiprocessing as multip

predictions_dict = {'A': [],
                    'B': [],
                    'C': [],
                    'D': [],
                    'E': [],
                    'F': [],
                    'Def': []}

data = [{'index': 1, 'rank': 'A'}, {'index': 2, 'rank': 'D'}, {'index': 3, 'rank': 'E'}]
prediction = [(1, 'C'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'D')]


def create_predictions_dict(index, rank):
    for j in data:
        if j['index'] == index:
            return index, j['rank'], rank

np = multip.cpu_count()
p = multip.Pool(processes=np)
sk = p.starmap(create_predictions_dict, prediction)
p.close()
p.join()

for elem in sk:
    predictions_dict[elem[2]].append(elem)

print('final list:', predictions_dict['D'])
```